# Moving webservices to point to on virtual directory

Tags: c#, web-services

Currently we have 5 web services each one configured in IIS with their own virtual directory.

We have now moved all the webservices into the same virtual directory folder.

Will this have any impact on performance or any other problems?

JD.

Comment: WCF or ASMX? What .NET Version?

Comment: Hi John. ASMX with ASP.net version 2.0 (we are currently using IIS 6)

Answer (score 1):

Just a couple of things to keep in mind.

- By consolidating your previously
  separate web services into a single
  virtual directory, you now have a
  single web application. That means
  that you're losing your ability to
  configure each web service
  separately. All five web services will
  use the same request queue for the
  application pool that your web
  application is assigned to. If
  several of your web services are
  getting high traffic, it may cause
  the requests coming to the other ones
  to queue. Note that this would still
  be the case if you had your web
  services separate but assigned to the
  same application pool. However, then
  you would have had the option and
  flexibility of creating a new
  application pool and assigning your
  web services appropriately. Also, each application pool has a recycle setting. It may recycle after so many requests. So if you have one or more high traffic web services, they may cause the worker process recycle and affect the other low traffic but critical web services for example. If you have some data cached for critical web services, you would lose them.
- You can't take down some of the web services and leave the others ones running. You may want to take one or two offline while still keeping the others running. Previously, you could have shutdown their application pools but now you can't do that because that would mean the other web services that you want to keep running will also be shutdown. You can rename the corresponding asmx or svc files to take some services offline but that just does not sound right.
- You may want to configure the application pools for some of the web services differently for recycling, performance, health, and identity. However, now that they're all part of the same web application, you can't.

These may or may not be important or critical in your case. Nonetheless, I want to mention so that you take them into consideration if you have not already done so.

Comment: I really don't know that the first point is significant since they would have seen the exact same thing using separate virtual directories. They would still have had to move one or more services to a different App Pool. Unless the OP had each virtual directory in a separate app pool, there was no ability to take each down separately. Overall, -1.

Comment: I disagree with you John. When you have them separate, at least you have the ability to configure them the way you want it such as assigning each or some to different app pools. When you consolidate them, you no longer have that option. I don't know if that's significant or not in OPs case but those are good things to know and consider. You downgrading my answer is not really right because I think I made some good points.

Answer (score 0):

No, there should be no impact on performance, or other problems.